# Preventing Windows 7 embedded standard shutdown 

Tags: winapi, shutdown, windows-7-embedded

Other similar question mostly target Windows XP, where everything was easier. =)

I'd like my application to be able to postpone the windows shutdown transparently, without having windows show this screen:

[image: windows 7 shutdown screen]

Is there any option left to me after the Vista changes to the WM_QUERYENDSESSION handling?

The target here is Windows 7 standard embedded on an embedded device that runs only my application. Before shutting down the user needs to perform some manual steps that can not be postponed until the next start and must not be forgotten. I'd like to have the user confirm these steps before shutting down.

Comment: Re: "Before shutting down the user needs to perform some manual steps" - Why not make those manual steps an automatic part of application exit? Having software do things for you automatically is kind of the entire point of software in the first place. Not to mention that if I have already decided to shut down the computer it most likely that means I want your app to go away as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The manual steps are not something the software can do. Its something like cleaning the instrument, replacing certain bottles etc. This is not software for a "normal" computer, but for an embedded device and the user has no prior expectations about what the power button should or should not do.

Comment: I see. In that case, I wouldn't worry about it. The "remember to clean the instrument" problem is best solved by user training/education, not by software. Not everything is solved best via a computer.

Comment: Hehe, true. But a I still would like to remind the user as strongly as possible to not damage a rather expensive piece of labratory equipment. =)

Comment: Right. I've worked in a lab with plenty of expensive equipment, so I know exactly what you're talking about. But the solution my university used is to simply put a big post-it note next to the power button reminding people to maintain it properly. :-)

Comment: I think Jens's concern is valid. If he has a chance to also warn the user via software, why not use it? That's what user-friendliness is all about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion, that there is no way to do this. =/

The workaround I've found is to allow shutdown only via the software at opportune moments. The start menu or task manager is not available to the user, and the hardware power button behavior can be configured to do nothing in the systems power options.